# Opening Outlook in from python

Tags: outlook

Trying to open outlook in an application sending email using below code

```
        selected_data = data[data["Task"] == selected_task]

        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

        for index, row in selected_data.iterrows():
            recipient_email = row["Email"]
            subject = f"Regarding {selected_task}"
            body = f"Dear {row['Name']}," \
                   f"\n\nPlease be informed about the {selected_task} task." \
```

Code says email ready for review in outlook, but outlook is not opened! Any help to resolve this

Comment: You are just creating an instance of the Outlook.Application object, but you don't create or display any messages or folders.